# Python Inheritance Issue

Tags: python, inheritance, subclass

I have a class that is inheriting from another class, and I get the issue:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 45, in <module>
    class Player(Entity):
  File "main.py", line 53, in Player
    self.image = pygame.image.load('sam_stand.png')
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

These are the classes:

```
class RigidBody(object):
    def __init__(self, (x, y), size, mass=1):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.size = size
        self.mass = mass
        self.thickness = 0
        self.angle = 0
        self.drag = 1
        self.elasticity = 0.9

class Player(Entity):
    """Player class.  Provides all player variables and methods"""
    def __init__(self):
        RigidBody.__init__(self)
        self.grounded = True
        self.direction = "Right"
        self.axis = "Down"
        self.jump_counter = 0
        self.image = pygame.image.load('sam_stand.png')
```

How come `self` is recognized for all the other attributes for the `Player`, except for `self.image`?  If I change it to `image = pygame.image.load('sam_stand.png')` the problem goes away.

Comment: Your traceback is incomplete, you forgot to include the exception message.

Comment: with `RigidBody.__init__(self)` you are calling RigidBody's constructor passing it your present object (i.e. an instance of Player).... what is your goal?

Comment: @Pynchia: that's perfectly normal behaviour, calling the parent class `__init__` method, but it is *unbound* so you need to pass in `self` explicitly. In new-style classes that'd be done with `super(Player, self).__init__()`

Comment: @MartijnPieters Entity != RigidBody, is it not?

Comment: You're not inheriting from `RigidBody`

Comment: @Pynchia: good point. *and* the `RigidBody.__init__()` method takes positional (required!) arguments!

Comment: I don't think `__init__(self, (x, y), size, mass=1)` is valid. You can't have `(x, y)` as a parameter.

Comment: @PeterWood: you can in Python 2.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Really? I never knew that!

Comment: @PeterWood: The syntax was [removed from Python 3](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/) though.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I just tried it. So you can do tuple unpacking in the parameter list. I'm not sure I like it.

Comment: So `Player` is currently not inheriting from `RigidBody` while written this way?

Comment: Your exception shows you have an **indentation** problem. The line is not part of the `__init__` method. Hunt down all tabs and convert them to spaces.

Comment: yep, it's inheriting from `Entity`. Please publish the definition of such class as well, if it exists

Comment: @tear728: all you do is run the `RigidBody.__init__` with the `Player` instance as `self`. That may set those attributes, but doesn't give you the rest of the class definition.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: What is the proper way give this class definition then?  Is that what `super(Player, self).__init__()` is for?

Comment: @tear728: you'd have to add `RigidBody` as a base class. You'll also need to use `super()` however, or call *both* `Entity.__init__()` and `RigidBody.__init__()` directy.

Comment: @tear728: watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EiOglTERPEo and read https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/ for more details.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Awesome, thanks for the lightning fast responses.  I'll check those out and make the changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mixing tabs and spaces. When looking at your first revision source I see this:

[image]

Your method body is indented with tabs, which Python expands to *8 spaces*. The last line, however, is indented with *spaces only*. You have your editor set to *4* spaces per tab, so you cannot see this mistake.

As a result, the `self.image` line falls *outside* the `__init__` method. It is part of the *class definition* instead.

You really want to configure your editor to indent with spaces *only*.

Run your code with `python -tt scriptname.py` and fix all the errors that reports. Then run the tabs-to-spaces feature in your text editor (converting to 4 spaces) and then configure it to use spaces for indentation (automatically inserting 4 spaces when you use the tab key).

Using spaces for indentation is [recommended by the Python styleguide](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces) for a reason, after all.

Comment: I see.  Wow, weird.  I guess that would make sense.   I will change all that and save myself a ton of trouble in the future. Thanks guys

Comment: I think you are also going to have to revisit the line `RigidBody.__init__(self)`. LOL

Comment: @RobertB: that's a separate issue, not the cause of the error. The revisiting is happening in the comments on the question.

Comment: I agree. You solved it and I gave you the up-vote. Just letting him know that that will be his next error.